# How should one save different method's parameters in a DB?

Tags: c#, reflection, rdbms

I have recently started working on a side-project making a "Magic: The Gathering"-style card game with C#, just for my personal development as a programmer.

A card can either be a "Monster" or a "Spell", and I would like to fire certain events whenever a particular scenario happens (for example, a Monster heals another friendly Monster whenever it gets hit; or a Spell deals damage when an enemy Monster is put on the board).

Currently I am storing all my cards in an RDBMS, where I have tables like "Monster" and "MonsterTrigger". The latter holds a MonsterId, TriggerType, and MethodName. When a Monster is loaded, I check whether it has any Trigger effects, and associate the corresponding EventHandler to it, which then calls the method specified in the MethodName column via Reflection.

My question is, how should I save the methods' parameters in the db? Methods can have different number of parameters, different data types, etc. (For example *DestroyAllMonsters()* vs *DrawCards(numOfCards)* vs. *Heal(monsterId, hp)*). My initial thought was to just save the parameters as comma-delimited or something along those lines, but this doesn't seem like good practice.
My other idea was to switch over to a NoSQL DB, but I would really like to keep everything on a RDBMS for this project if I can help it.

I would very much like to hear your suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'll start this with the assumption that you're not using objects and object inheritance for whatever reason (as my first thought would be to suggest objects and something like a factory or builder design pattern to build the cards) that you have already justified with yourself and not go down that path.

For the RDBMS you'd want to split out anything that needs further definition into other tables and link with foreign keys.  Since Methods vary and may or may not have parameters I'd split them out, have a table for the parameters and use a junction table to connect methods with their parameters and store the method id with the card.  This makes the MethodName column match more with a relational DB structure than the way you've built it.

Comment: Hello Charles and thank you for the answer about the DB structure. It was very helpful! As for the code, I am using object inheritance - I have a Monster class and a Spell class, both of which implement a Card interface. Do you suggest that I should do it differently? I'm open to ideas, this is mostly an exercise for myself

Comment: It really depends on how objects get their functionality.  It sounds like you have generic objects and you're using a database to define the functionality.  I'm guessing that you want to the ability to create cards without having to add code (unless new methods are needed) which means working with generics so interfaces can work for that.  It also means a pretty complex data model to support that functionality.